# Can't import tf2 into jupyter notecook

Tags: jupyter-notebook, tensorflow2.0

I have just installed tensorflow2, but when I open a jupyter notebook and import tensorflow, when I do print(tf.**version**) I get a 1.13 version.

Answer (score 0):

If `tf.__version__` gives you `1.13` is becase in the current environment you have TensorFlow 1.13 installed.

You can have a look at every package installed in the current environment by using `pip freeze` and looking at the list.

However, to be sure you are working in an environment where TensorFlow 2.0 is installed, you can create a [virtualenv](https://virtualenv.pypa.io/en/latest/) and install therein everything you need with `pip`.

Remember to install also the jupyter notebook package inside your virtual environment, otherwise you will execute the system jupyter notebook and it will load the TensorFlow package installed at system-level.

Hope it helps

Comment: Thanks so much for your response. I am confused with pip and pip3. In pip I have tf 2.0 installed, whereas in pip3 I have both tf 1.13 and 2.0 (plus tf estimator 1.13, tf estimator nightly 1.15 and tf nightly 1.14).

Comment: Because you have (as almost everyone) installed both Python 2 (that uses pip) and Python 3 (that uses pip3). I highly recommend to create a virtualenv that uses the python 3 interpreter (you can create it with `-p python 3.6` if I remember correctly) and only use it. The other reccomendation is to remove every tensorflow package from the system (in both the py2 and py3 envs), so when you create a new environment you don't risk to use some systemwide installed package